# Firebase Service Authentication

Tags: java, firebase

We would like to push data from our Java REST service into Firebase for clients to receive. We are batching these changes, and Firebase transactions are ideal for this situation. What is not ideal however is that the JVM client authentication options aren't ideal for services. We don't want to start and maintain a session, we would rather pass a JWT or our FB secret with each request. Is there a recommended authentication technique for server-side clients of Firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authenticating a client using the Firebase Java SDK is effectively establishing a session. If you're asking for a recommended authentication technique, that would be it.

If you don't want that, you may consider calling the [Firebase REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/) from Java. That takes the authentication token as a parameter.